# Cython C-Type definition

Tags: types, cython

To make my Cython code more faster, I like to declare variable types as much as possible.

```
cpdef void __init__(self, config, protocol=None, int slave_number, int fifo_length=170, float speed_factor=1.0) except *:
        assert 0 < config.watermark_height <= fifo_length
        assert protocol is None
        assert slave_number is int
        self.config = config
        self.protocol = protocol
        self.slave_number = slave_number
        self.speed_factor = speed_factor
```

2 questions:

1. How do I declare the self.slave_number variable as int?#
2. Is the assertion (e.g. slave_numbers is int) unnecessary if I cp-function parameter already says its an int?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The variables from the [*Extension type*](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/tutorial/cdef_classes.html) are defined in the class declaration. In your situation:

   ```
   cdef class SpeedClass:
       cdef int slave_number
       cdef ...
   ```
2. A call to `__init__` will cast the argument to an integer and error when the operation is impossible. You can thus pass a floating point value to the function. From inside the function, `slave_numbers` is always an integer as it will have been casted at call-time anyway and the check is useless. I couldn't find this information explicitly in the docs so I have tested it with a small example (see below).

   ```
   def f1(int i):
       print(type(i))
       return i*2
   ```

   that you can test from the command line as

   ```
   python3 -c 'import test_arguments; print(test_arguments.f1(1))'
   ```

   or

   ```
   python3 -c 'import test_arguments; print(test_arguments.f1(1.23))'
   ```